# Tracking Facebook Mobile Ads with Google Analytics

Tags: android, facebook, google-analytics, google-play

I want to track the installs that I am getting from **Facebook mobile ads** using **Google Analytics**.

To track the installs from this campaign, Google has provided me with a **custom campaign URL** appended with all the necessary parameters.

However, there is no way to integrate this parameter in Facebook Mobile Ads, as all they use the **package name and class name** to reach the application on **play store**.

Is there any way to **insert the campaign URL into FB Mobile Ads**? Can the parameters be appended to the package name?

TIA

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find an answer?

Comment: Same here. Did you ever find a work-around? I'm experimenting with an ad to a bitly url seeing as facebook keeps stripping out any parameters to a play store url.

Comment: Same Issue here. Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook help center page [How do I use URL tags?](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732) says:

> Note that for mobile app ads there is no URL tags field, only a deep
>   link field. The URL tag field only appears for Canvas app ads.

It's not possible to do that right now as Facebook doesn't allow you to pass any referral parameters - you can only set the Android App name (no way to use a standard URL.)

I was told that something could be done using certified tracking partners. As far as I know, they could send a request to Facebook to find out if a user has previously clicked your ads.

Anyhow, you still have to trust on Facebook reports and you cannot audit the traffic.

Comment: Would be great if you add dates to the answer when you say `right now` (for further reference), also if you make that assertion, it's good idea to include source links.

Answer (score 0):

Another confirmation that you cannot achieve it currently without going to Facebook partners.

https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/pixel/facebook_pixel/?act=848281788635562&pid=p1&business_id=618211764975900

I think that what you can do is a workaround by tricky using deep linking mechanism. You can pass some info via deep link URL and on the Android app side - post an event to your backend informing that there was such deep link parameter passed. 
Some additional work, no data on Google Analytics, only in your custom backend - it is up to you if it's worth it.

Answer (score -1):

On Android, the android SDK actually has libraries to process that referral:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#general-campaigns

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand the question. It's not a programming question, it is a Facebook ads question: Facebook removes the campaign data from the URL provided by the user. Why, and how to resolve - that's the question